# Bulk query CampaignMemper query failed

Tags: bulk-api

I am running into the following error while querying CampaignMember:

> -------------- Failed ----------CampaignMember [BatchInfo  id='751c0000001HqUQAA0'  jobId='750c0000001Mpg1AAC'  state='Failed' 
>   **stateMessage='InvalidBatch : Failed to process query: INVALID_FIELD: 
>   SystemModstamp, FirstRespondedDate, Name,
>   tt_itda_watch__Tech_Target_Import_Timestamp__c**
>   ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:174 No such column 'Name' on entity
>   'CampaignMember'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure
>   to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your
>   WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.' 
>   createdDate='java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1440705023000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2015,MONTH=7,WEEK_OF_YEAR=35,WEEK_OF_MONTH=5,DAY_OF_MONTH=27,DAY_OF_YEAR=239,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=1,HOUR=7,HOUR_OF_DAY=19,MINUTE=50,SECOND=23,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]'  systemModstamp='java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1440705023000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2015,MONTH=7,WEEK_OF_YEAR=35,WEEK_OF_MONTH=5,DAY_OF_MONTH=27,DAY_OF_YEAR=239,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=1,HOUR=7,HOUR_OF_DAY=19,MINUTE=50,SECOND=23,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]'  numberRecordsProcessed='0'  numberRecordsFailed='0' 
>   totalProcessingTime='0'  apiActiveProcessingTime='0' 
>   apexProcessingTime='0' ]

And the query is:

```
SELECT Id, IsDeleted, CampaignId, LeadId, ContactId, Status, HasResponded, CreatedDate, CreatedById, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedById, SystemModstamp, FirstRespondedDate, Name, tt_itda_watch__Tech_Target_Import_Timestamp__c FROM CampaignMember WHERE SystemModStamp <= 2015-08-28T12:23:26.760Z
```

Running the query in Developer console does not return any error message.
The problem disappears when I remove the Name field. Is this an issue from Salesforce and if not, how can I replicate the data using Bulk API?

Answer (score 2):

When querying "name" off of CampaignMember, you're actually referring to the name of a contact or lead that the campaignMember record has a relationship with. So unlike the field "Name" on Account or a similar object, you're not referring to the CampaignMember's name, you're attempting to refer to a compound field which is the FirstName + LastName value retrieved from the Contact or Lead.

Although I'm not an expert on this, there are some situations where the Developer Console will let you query compound fields without issue, but if you try that in an Apex class, it won't let you.

So if you want to retrieve the "name" values, I'd suggest putting

Contact.FirstName, Contact.LastName

or

Lead.FirstName, Lead.LastName

Or both of those in your query (depending on whether you're looking for lead campaigns, contact campaigns, or all campaigns), in place of "Name".

Comment: The problem is I do not know what ones that I have to look for - Contact or Lead. So, the solution should be running two separate batches using the where clause `where LeadId != null` and `where ContactId != null`. I guess I can use Contact.Name instead of FirstName, LastName fields.

Comment: Relationship query not supported through Bulk. Therefore, this solution is not possible!

Comment: You are correct, I overlooked the "bulk API" note at the end of your original description, my apologies. However, you had mentioned batches in your follow up comment - it would work there.

Comment: What I meant was create a job and use individual batches to integrate. As I would require name field, the batch will still fail.