# Bulk API - Invalid field 'Revision' on FeedItem

Tags: soql, bulk-api, chatter-feed

I query FeedItem on all fields using **Bulk-API**. This is the query:

```
SELECT Id, ParentId, Type, CreatedById, CreatedDate, IsDeleted, LastModifiedDate, SystemModstamp, Revision, LastEditById, LastEditDate, CommentCount, LikeCount, Title, Body, LinkUrl, RelatedRecordId, ContentFileName, ContentDescription, ContentType, ContentSize, InsertedById, BestCommentId, HasContent, HasLink FROM FeedItem
```

and I get the bulk job failed stating:

> -------------- Failed ----------FeedItem [**BatchInfo   state='Failed' stateMessage='InvalidBatch : Failed to process query: INVALID_FIELD: 
>   LastModifiedDate, SystemModstamp, Revision, LastEditById, LastEditDate
>   ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:99 No such column 'Revision' on entity
>   'FeedItem'**. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to
>   append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your
>   WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.'
>   createdDate='java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1441115985000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2015,MONTH=8,WEEK_OF_YEAR=36,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_YEAR=244,DAY_OF_WEEK=3,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=1,HOUR=1,HOUR_OF_DAY=13,MINUTE=59,SECOND=45,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]' systemModstamp='java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1441115985000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2015,MONTH=8,WEEK_OF_YEAR=36,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_YEAR=244,DAY_OF_WEEK=3,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=1,HOUR=1,HOUR_OF_DAY=13,MINUTE=59,SECOND=45,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]' numberRecordsProcessed='0' numberRecordsFailed='0'
>   totalProcessingTime='0' apiActiveProcessingTime='0'
>   apexProcessingTime='0' ]

This may be similar to the [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/89789/bulk-query-campaignmemper-query-failed). I am not sure whether this is an issue only for FeedItem. Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1):

The field `Revision` in `FeedItem` object is added in the Summer'15 which comes with a feature called `Chatter Post Feed Editing`.

The feature should be manually enabled by the Administrator or the one who have Customize Application system permission.

For the orgs which doesn't have this feature enabled, there won't be any new fields available.

Please check the [Knowledge Article 000214510](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=How-can-I-enable-Chatter-Post-Feed-Editing-for-my-organization&language=en_US) for more information on enabling this feature.